# call a method in code-behind from client side script

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I'm using `asp.net.`

I want to update a part of my page (not whole page) without sending the page request to the server. I want to do this in the client side.

for this, I think I should use `AJAX` and `javascript`.

I've created a handler page: `handler.ashx`

I send a request and get response in plain text:

**Javascript**

```
  XMLHttpRequest.open("GET", url);
//ApplyUpdate is a function that get the response in client side.
  XMLHttpRequest.onreadystate = ApplyUpdate; 
  XMLHttpRequest.send(null);
```

**Code** on handler.ashx

```
response.write("plain text as response");
```

Now in ApplyUpdate function I can use the plain text and show it in client browser.

BUT the problem is this:

I have a placeholder1 control in asp.net:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

How can I assign the plain text (the response !)  to a label control and add the label to 
`placeholder1` control !?
I mean how I can use these codes in client side:

```
Label lb1 = new Lable();
lb1.text = plaintext;
placeholder1.controls.add(lb1);
```

these codes are in `c#` (code-behind) but how I can use such these codes?
I cannot do the same thing by `javascript` codes !

excuse my bad explanation.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: You can also using AJAX UpdatePanel control to achieve this

Comment: @Satindersingh The UpdatePanel is easier, but slower from my understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the element in JavaScript using the response text and append it to the placeholder. If the placeholder is used explicitly for this label, you can remove it and just append it to its parent.

This is how you create the element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement